# css - one box dictates height, other width

Tags: html, css, positioning

What is the best way to have two divs, left and right of each other, where one dictates the width, and the other dictates the height:

CSS:

```
body
{
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
}

.wholething
{
    background-color:red;
}

.leftside
{
    width:230px;
    background-color:blue;
}
.rightside
{
    height:640px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wholething">
    <div class="leftside">
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    </div>
</div>
```

The result would look like a blue box 230px wide and 640 px high, and a green box 730 px wide and 640 px high. Then, if the CSS is changed for width or height, both boxes will adjust accordingly. Please only add to the css; do not remove css unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
    width:960px; 
    margin:auto; 
}
.wholething {
    background-color:red;
    position: relative;
    height: 640px;
} 
.leftside { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width:230px; 
    background-color:blue; 
} 
.rightside { 
    position: absolute;
    left: 230px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom:0px; 
    background-color:green; 
}
```

That'll work. However you will need to change the `left` of the second one to match the `width` of the first.

Comment: The leftside box has a zero height with this CSS.

Comment: It has `top` and `bottom` of `0px`, so it will fill the height og the container...

Comment: Ah, right yes. You're right, it's because the container also has zero height. See edit.